# Compute specificity and sensitivity at certain thresholds

Tags: classification, self-study

I have the following table with predictive probabilities and true class labels:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
P(T=1) &0.54& 0.23 & 0.78 & 0.88 & 0.26 & 0.41 & 0.90 & 0.45&0.19&0.36 \\ \hline
 T&1&0 &0 &1 &0 &0& 1& 1& 0& 0\\ \hline
\end{array}

The question is to compute the specificity & sensitivity at the threshold of 0.5.

---

My attempt at answering this question:

**Sensitivity** = true positive rate[P(T=1) > 0.5]

= (0.54 + 0.88 + 0.9)/4 = 0.58

**Specificity** = 1-false positive rate[P(T=1) > 0.5]

= 1- [(0.78)/6]
 = 0.87

Not sure if my working above is correct. I would appreciate if someone can guide me to the correct solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For threshold = $0.5$ we have:

**Sensitivity** = True Positive Rate

= (number of points with label $1$ and $P(T = 1)\geq 0.5$) divided by (number of points with label $1$)

= $\left|\{(1, 0.54), (1, 0.88), (1, 0.90)\}\right| / 4$ = $3/4$ = $0.75$

**Specificity** = 1 - False Positive Rate

= 1 - (number of points with label $0$ and $P(T = 1)\geq 0.5$) divided by (number of points with label $0$)

= $1 - \left|\{(0, 0.78)\}\right|/6$ =  $1 - 1/6$ = $0.833$